# how to Hide dropdownfor in razor view in mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to hide drop down according to class property value in asp.net mvc 3 razar view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply a CSS class to the dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemId, Model.Items, new { @class = "hidden" })
```

and then define the hidden CSS class:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

This hidden class could of course be applied dynamically based on some property value of the view model. For example you could write a custom HTML helper which could be used like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedItemId, 
    Model.Items, 
    Html.GetHtmlAttributes(Model.IsHidden)
)
```

where the `GetHtmlAttributes` is a custom extension method that you could write:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary GetHtmlAttributes(bool isHidden)
    {
        if (!isHidden)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new RouteValueDictionary(new { @class = "hidden" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to simply exclude the dropdown completely?

```
@if (!Model.DontShowDropdown)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(....)
}
```

or, do you want to hide it?

```
Html.DropDownListFor(..., new { "style" = Model.DontShowDropDown ? "display:none" : "" };
```

Comment: @pargan, what was the full code you used that resulted in a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this ex:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("mydropdown", new SelectList(new[] {
    new SelectListItem{ Value = "0",Text="Item1"},
    new SelectListItem{ Value = "1",Text="Item2"},
    new SelectListItem{ Value = "2",Text="Item3"},
    new SelectListItem{ Value = "3",Text="Item4"}
}, "Value", "Text", "2"), new
{
    id = "mydropdown",
    @class = "myddClass",
    style = ""
})
```

in css add **#mydropdown** or **.myddClass**, then you can add **display:none;** in external css or add add it to inline css like **style = "display:none;"**